# QMessageBox halts QTimer

Tags: qt

I created a `QMessageBox` instance with single button "OK" in slot connected to `QTimer` signal `timeout()` and displayed it using `exec` function and it seems that timer halts until button pressed and the box closed. I expected `exec` to create local event loop and dispatching timer messages, nevertheless timer was halted (no signal `timeout()` emited). Can anyone explain? P.S Sorry for my english.

UPDATE:
sample code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
      QMainWindow(parent),
      ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  QTimer *tm1=new QTimer(this),
  *tm2=new QTimer(this);

  connect(tm1,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(tslot1()));
  connect(tm2,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(tslot2()));
  tm1->start(1000);
  tm2->start(1000);
}

void MainWindow::tslot1(void)
{
  static int cnt;
  qWarning(QString("slot 1 called %1 time(s)").arg(++cnt).toAscii().data());
}

void MainWindow::tslot2(void)
{
  static int cnt;
  qWarning(QString("slot 2 called %1 time(s)").arg(++cnt).toAscii().data());
  if (3==cnt)
  {
    QMessageBox *mb=new QMessageBox(QMessageBox::Critical,tr("Error"),tr("tm2 halted !"),QMessageBox::Ok,this);
    mb->exec();
  }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  delete ui;
}
```

Comment: See my edit in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can see that event loop is running, because `timer1` is firing timeouts. From [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#exec) you can see that `exec()` is blocking call - so it will block the caller function (QTimer slot) until dialog is closed.

That leads us to the `QObject` source code. After executing slot function, in `QMetaObject::activate`, last step is to reset the sender of the signal:

`QObjectPrivate::resetCurrentSender(receiver, &currentSender, previousSender);`

This will reset `QTimer` state, and it will start countdown again. I think this is the common-sense approach to ensure that timer callbacks are called sequentially - like timers in most UI libraries, and not in parallel within the **same** timer.

Because `exec()` will block timer callback, `QTimer` will not be reset and callback will not be called again (until function resumes, and `QTimer` gets its reset).

You have several ways in handling this:

1) If you don't want your function to block, and you don't need result of modal dialog to proceed with the function - call `QMessageBox::open()` instead of `QMessageBox::exec()` - it will not block the caller function.

2) If you need result of the dialog to continue the function, and you don't want to stop your timer callbacks, naive approach is to reset `QTimer` manually by calling `QTimer::stop()` and `QTimer::start()` sequentially when entering the callback function.

Comment: Thanks, you been very helpful. I decited to use QMessageBox::open.